# Is there any way that we can save/ record the data that is played on audioTrack in android

Tags: java, android, audiotrack

I want to record the audio that is played by using the audio track. Can someone please help me out on this

Answer (score 0):

The audio data you're seeking exists independently of AudioTrack and is "fed" to it... and then to the speakers in a one-way flow:

[data] ---->----> [audiotrack] ---->----> [speakers]

The AudioTrack class doesn't offer any public methods for intercepting the data between audiotrack and the speakers.

Somewhere in your code you have a variable, let's call it 'data' of type byte[], short[], float[], or ByteBuffer.

Somewhere in your code you're playing/feeding this data to your AudioTrack... lets call it "track."

So in code it looks like this:

track.write(data, ... ,... ,...);

Where the ... is other arguments depending on the write() method you have chosen... [see documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack).

Anyway, so now you know you actually already have the data.

We know this because (unless you created a raw byte array by typing with the keyboard), it has already been either recorded or saved.

Maybe the class you're looking for is one of the recording classes like [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) or [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder).